# Shiftkey is triggered when I am trying to click the shift + tab combination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`Shiftkey` is triggered when I am trying to click the `shift + tab` combination

```
$("#buttonZZ").on("keydown",function (eve) {
    if (eve.keyCode == 9 && eve.shiftKey) {
       eve.preventDefault();
       $("#cancelbtn").focus();
    }
    if (eve.keyCode == 9) {
       eve.preventDefault();
       $("#feedback_1").focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't see any questions

Answer (score 0):

please try below piece of code and it might solve your issue.

```js
$("#buttonZZ").on("keydown",function (eve) {
        if(eve.keyCode == 9) {
            if(eve.shiftKey) {
               //Focus previous input
            }
            else {
               //Focus next input
            }
          }
    });
```